# Behaviour different when debugging

Tags: c++, random

I'm creating a TicTacToe Game, with classes, using C++ for school.

Part2 requires me to implement a single player mode (me vs the computer).

I have a matrix 3x3 and the function to randomly insert coordinates (CPU's move) always plays in the main diagonal (1,1;2,2;3,3).

If I put a breakpoint when I call the "random" method and debug step by step, it creates other coordinates, besides the main diagonal (which is good).

I don't understand why it only works if I'm debugging step by step.

Here's the random method:

```
void Ponto::aleatorio() {
    srand(GetTickCount());
    x = (rand() % 3)+1;

    srand(GetTickCount());
    y = (rand() % 3)+1;
}
```

Comment: Call `srand(GetTickCount());` exactly once (e.g. from `main()`, not every time your function is called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does rand() return the same value using srand(time(null)) in this for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644593/why-does-rand-return-the-same-value-using-srandtimenull-in-this-for-loop)

Comment: wth really? Thanks .It's amazing,and kinda fustrating how a single line of code can disrupt my program.Even my teacher couldn´t see the problem.thanks alot.I just remove the extra srand(GetTickCount()); line y = (rand() % 3)+1;

Comment: @Ferro It's not that you have two calls to `srand` in `aleatorio`, but that you're calling `aleatorio` multiple times in a row.

Comment: "Random" is not random, it's "pseudo random". Dont set `srand` twice, set it only once. At each call of `rand()` you will get a new value for sure. Or eventually the same, but it will be more random for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling srand with a value, this value is used as the seed to start the random number generator.  Generating random numbers with the same seed will generate the same sequence.  Since you're using GetTickCount() to seed the generator, the program is running before the next clock tick, so are always calling srand with same argument.  Like @πάντα ῥεῖ said, call it with GetTickCount() once, then call it without args to get the next number in random sequence.

Comment: It's not "*always* calling srand with same argument", but rather "possibly" or "most likely". The tick count *could* change between the two GetTickCount() calls - though it's more likely than not to stay the same in this simple case.

Comment: yes, correct, but if when not running in debugger the numbers are the same, then clock tick is not changing between calls.